# how to use printf in C++

Tags: c++, c

i have 2 commands

```
printf("%2i%2i", 3, 5);

printf("%7.2f %2i\n", 34.56, 1);
```

see how the `%2i` moves "5" 2 units to the right for the first `printf` command

but for

```
printf("%7.2f %2i\n", 34.56, 1);
```

the "1" is 3 moved spaces  after  the number `34.56`?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: 1. Why use `printf` in C++. 2. Why tag it `c`?

Answer (score 4):

> the "1" is 3 moved spaces after the number 34.56 ?

The reason is that there is an extra space in the second formatting string:

```
printf("%2i%2i", 3, 5);
printf("%7.2f %2i\n", 34.56, 1);
          // ^here
```

Answer (score 1):

Well those numbers you use are called field widths.They specify the number of characters to be used to represent a number.

Since 5 is a single digit number `%2d` uses 1 block to print 5 and aapplies a leading space.

Similarly the output for `printf("%7.2f %2i\n" , 34.56 , 1 );`  will be :

`..34.56..1`

**Note : The '.'(dot) represents a blank space**

So it will print **`1`** 2 spaces after the number **`34.56`**